# how to extract data from "https://www.covid19india.org/" to data frame district level covid cases in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

so I have  tried traditional

```
data <- curl("https://www.covid19india.org")
```

or

```
readLines("https://www.covid19india.org")
```

but was not able to extract data.
the data I want is at the district level which we can see after click example if we go on this URL and click Maharashtra then we can see all districts related to Maharashtra.
similarly for all districts.
any guidance will be of great help

Comment: You should interface [this api](https://api.covid19india.org/) and get [this](https://api.covid19india.org/state_district_wise.json) for state/district wise

Answer (score 0):

my humble solution to your problem would be to use RSelenium to remote control a webbrowser, access the page you are showing and click on the element you whish to open. After his a page-read should show the required information.

Raw Example to show it works (just tried it):

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
```

I use firefox but there is chrome and other options

```
driver <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox")
remDr <- driver[['client']]
```

Navivate to the page

```
remDr$navigate("https://www.covid19india.org/")
```

Get the content of the Page to R & read as html:

```
src <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
pg <- read_html(src)
```

There is no mumbai information as you informed:

```
no_mumbai <- pg %>% html_node(xpath='/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody[1]') %>% html_text()
```

Get the Button by css selector and then "click" on it:

```
maharastra <- remDr$findElement(using = "css selector", ".table > tbody:nth-child(2) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1)")
maharastra$clickElement()
```

Get the content of the Page to R & read as html:

```
src <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
pg <- read_html(src)
```

Now I just read the same info and mumbai shows up!

```
with_mumbai <- pg %>% html_node(xpath='/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody[1]') %>% html_text()
```

This code is not perfect (probably far away from it) but it does the job. You would have to combine it with loops and parsing to get the clean info. Most probably there are better data sources like an governmental API.